# Identity user manager find by phonenumber

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In aspnet core identity2.0, Is there anyway to find a user by its phone number? The [`UserManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Methods) can find a user by its username and email, but there isn't a find by phone or even better, a generic `find(Func<TUser, bool>)` function provided. When user register with phone, need to check if a given phone number already existed, because a phone cannot be used by two users.

edit

start auth code:

```
services.AddIdentity<AccountUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AccountDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Comment: What does your startup.Auth look like? Are you overridding any of the OWIN components? If not, you will need to create a new custom `UserStore` and if you want this in the `UserManager` possibly a new one of those too.

Comment: I didn't use OWIN, just identity, could you elaborate on UserStore?

Comment: Now I think about it. Why don't you just query the tables directly? You can jump though a load of hoops to override all the auth components but really if you want to know if that username is unique, just check the database?

Comment: Yeah, right, I got DbContext in the api controller, so should be able to query anyway. Should not have focused on UserManager methods, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The UserManager class already offers a convenient method for achieving this task. You can directly use the Where LINQ method to filter users based on a specified condition, such as the phone number. This can be done by calling the Where method on the Users property exposed by creating an instance of the UserManager class.

```
await _userManager.Users.Where(x=>x.PhoneNumber == "PhoneToCheck").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to require unique Phone Numbers, you can do this in the `ApplicationDbContext` (or whatever context you are using as an IdentityDbContext) by adding this method:

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    if (entityEntry != null && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        var errors = new List<DbValidationError>();
        var user = entityEntry.Entity as ApplicationUser;
        //check for uniqueness of phone number
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (Users.Any(u => String.Equals(u.PhoneNumber, user.PhoneNumber)))
            {
                errors.Add(new DbValidationError("User",user.PhoneNumber+" is already registered."));
            }
        }
    }
    return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items); //check for uniqueness of user name and email and return result
}
```

The inherited `base.ValidateEntity` method is what checks to make sure the UserName and Email are unique (if you've specified these options in the configuration).

For using statements it looks like you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

As for the exact question you asked: to access the Phone Numbers you need direct access to the data context. As far as I know neither `UserManager` nor even `UserStore` implement such a method, though you could define your own user store class inheriting from `UserStore` to add such a method.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code**

UserStoreCustom.cs

```
 public class UserStoreCustom : UserStore<User>
    {
        public UserStoreCustom(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
            : base(context, describer)
        {

        }
        public virtual Task<User> FindByPhoneNumberAsync(string PhoneNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            return Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.PhoneNumber == PhoneNumber, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DataCenter")));
   
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(option =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                option.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
            })

                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserStore<UserStoreCustom>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddSingleton<UserStoreCustom>();
```